# Usercontrol within Usercontrol with Data Binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-controls

I built a simple WPF UserControl that I want to implement several of in another UserControl while maintaining the data binding.  I have a simple Debug1 window that implements (1) a bound textblock (to verify data binding only) & button; (2) a single instance of the NumericUpDownBox usercontrol with binding; and (3) an instance of the parent user control containing an instance of the child user control NumericUpDownBox.

Items (1) and (2) are working.  Item (3) does not.  I feel like I am missing something in the implementation in the parent user control code?  I also get a couple of errors that concern me (see below).

Debug1 Window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Debug1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CFIT"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Debug1" Height="225" Width="600"
    Closing="ClosingDebug1">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="NextButton" Content="Next" Click="ClickNext" Width="50" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Years, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <local:NumericUpDownBox Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="SingleBox" Label="TBD" Increment="2" Value="{Binding Path=Years}"/>
    <local:YMDH_TimeControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="TimeControl" YearsValue="{Binding Path=Years}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Debug Window VB Code:

```
Public Class Debug1
    Public Mat As New clsMaterial
    Sub New()  ' Removed for brevity
    End Sub
    Private Sub ClickNext(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Mat.Lives(0).MSDateOffset.Years = Mat.Lives(0).MSDateOffset.Years + 5
    End Sub
End Class
```

Parent UserControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YMDH_TimeControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CFIT"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="200" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="160"
         Name="YMDH_TimeControl">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=YMDH_TimeControl}">
    <local:NumericUpDownBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Years"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Parent UserControl VB Code:

```
Public Class YMDH_TimeControl
Public Shared ReadOnly YearsValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("YearsValue", GetType(Integer), GetType(YMDH_TimeControl), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, (FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault), Nothing, New CoerceValueCallback(AddressOf OnValueChanged)))

Private Shared Function OnValueChanged(d As DependencyObject, value As Object) As Object
    If IsNumeric(value) Then
        Return CInt(value)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

Public Property YearsValue As Integer
    Get
        Return Years.Value
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        Years.Value = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Child UserControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NumericUpDownBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CFIT"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="40"
             Name="NumericUpDownBox">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=NumericUpDownBox}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            ... removed for brevity...
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!--Box Definition-->
        <Border Style="{StaticResource SectionNameBorder}" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid Background="Gray" >
                <Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Name="LabelTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Label, ElementName=NumericUpDownBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Viewbox>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="White" >
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBox Name="ValueTextBox" BorderBrush="White" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=NumericUpDownBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <RepeatButton Name="UpArrow" Style="{StaticResource UpArrowStyle}" Tag="+" Click="TickValues" />
                        <RepeatButton Name="DownArrow" Style="{StaticResource DownArrowStyle}" Tag="-" Click="TickValues" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Child UserControl VB Code:

```
Public Class NumericUpDownBox
    Private Const DefaultInc As Integer = 1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        If Increment = 0 Then Increment = DefaultInc
    End Sub
    Private Sub TickValues(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim Sign As Char
        Dim Tag As String
        Tag = sender.tag.ToString
        If Len(Tag) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Sign = Left(Tag, 1)
        If Sign = "+" Then
            Value = Value + Increment
        ElseIf Sign = "-" Then
            Value = Value - Increment
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Property Value As Integer
        Get
            Return CInt(GetValue(ValueProperty))
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If value < 0 Then value = 0
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Label As String
        Get
            Return GetValue(LabelProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SetValue(LabelProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Increment As Integer
        Get
            Return CInt(GetValue(IncProperty))
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If value < 0 Then value = 0
            SetValue(IncProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(Integer), GetType(NumericUpDownBox), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, (FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault), Nothing, New CoerceValueCallback(AddressOf OnValueChanged)))
    Public Shared ReadOnly LabelProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", GetType(String), GetType(NumericUpDownBox), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""))
    Public Shared ReadOnly IncProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Increment", GetType(Integer), GetType(NumericUpDownBox), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, Nothing, New CoerceValueCallback(AddressOf OnValueChanged)))
    Private Shared Function OnValueChanged(d As DependencyObject, value As Object) As Object
        If IsNumeric(value) Then
            Return CInt(value)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Example Information Error in the Output Window:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Years; DataItem=null; target element is 'YMDH_TimeControl' (Name='TimeControl'); target property is 'YearsValue' (type 'Int32')

How do I get my data binding to pass through my parent user control?

Comment: `Years` property must be present in your `DataContext` which you set for your `DebugWindow`.

Comment: Sample code got big so I cut that out. `years` is included in the `DataContext` object.  It is working for the other 2 controls that are looking at the same `DataContext`.

Comment: I cant see where and how `Years` is used ? Where `NumericUpDownBox` is using `Years` ? I cant see any such binding for it.

Comment: From Debug1 xaml; binding path:
`<local:NumericUpDownBox Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="SingleBox" Label="TBD" Increment="2" Value="{Binding Path=Years}"/>`